# save a certain random number of turtles in a list

Tags: list, netlogo

I have 10 turtles and I want to work on 3 of them chosen randomly.
How do I select  3 turtles randomly and save those exact turtles to use them later?

I figured how to print the list I want to save

ask n-of 3 turtles  [print int (who )]

but I do not know how to save these turtles in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you want to save your random subset in an agentset, `saved-turtles`.  Then it would be

```
let saved-turtles n-of 3 turtles
```

If you wanted `saved-turtles` to be a list, then

```
let saved-turtles [self] of n-of 3 turtles
```

`sort` is also useful for turning an agentset into a list

```
let saved-turtles sort n-of 3 turtles
```

Hope this helps,
Charles

Comment: Note that in NetLogo it's usually easier and better to work with agentsets than it is to use lists of agents.